# Rust, write a generic function that define itself a type

Tags: function, generics, rust, parameters, traits

If I want a generic function to return a generic struct with a type defined based on some parameter, how can I implement that?
I have something like the following:

- Struct from other crate (outside of my control)

```
struct Foo{
   data_type: String,
   data_int32: Vec<i32>,
   data_int64: Vec<i64>,
   data_int32: Vec<f32>,
   data_int64: Vec<f64>,
   data_raw: Vec<u8>
}
```

- My struct

```
struct A<T>{
    data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> A<T>{
    fn new(data: T) -> Self{
        A{
            data: data
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<Foo> for A<T>{
    fn from(foo: Foo) -> Self{
        match foo.data_type{
            "i32" => A::new(foo.data_i32),
            "i64" => A::new(foo.data_i64),
            "f32" => A::new(foo.data_f32),
            "f64" => A::new(foo.data_f64),
            _ => A::new(foo.data_raw)
        }
    }
}
```

This return me the following error: `expected struct A<T> found struct A<i32>` or `expected struct A<T> found struct A<f32>` ecc...
I tried varius differrent solution like restricting the generic value with `T: From::<...>` but nothing works and I always fall back to this kind of error.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. What would the result type of this call be?

```
let o = A::new(random_bool());
```

Comment: Hopefully something like A<T>

Comment: @dimi_it and what would that T be? The only way to do this is something like `either`.

Comment: @IvanC I update the question with more information about my problem, how i can resolve that given that `either` is not a feasible solution in this case?

Comment: @dimit_it look at the dupe targets! Of course literal `either` with only two variants doesn't work nicely, but your own `enum A { S(String), V_I32(Vec<i32>), V_I64(Vec<i64>), …}` will.